# Avoid guessing of 'varying' in reshape()

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I'm trying to `reshape()` some time-varying data in R. I am working with the following dataset:

```
dframe <- structure(list(participant_id = structure(c(48L, 43L, 51L, 28L, 35L, 65L), .Label = c("PRA", "RA", "ASD", "LAD", "ASDGZV ", "RAGSD", "GREA", "SDFDSA", "DSFG", "FHJ", "RQGA", "AESFD", "RGAV", "FGHDF", "HSGD", "FDGH", "ASDF", "AGSD", "SADF", "SADF", "SF", "XV", "ASDCV", "ASDF", "ASDG", "SDF", "XCVZ", "ZXCV", "ASGV", "SAFDV", "ASDF", "SDFV", "SAFD", "SAFD", "AGS", "FDSGVX", "WAFDS", "DSAZC", "SADCZX", "SADFCX", "DSAFC", "FDSGV", "ADSCXZ", "SDFACZ", "SADFCZ", "AFSDZX", "EAWFDSZ", "FDVCZX", "SADZC", "FSADCZ", "AESFDZC", "WAFDSZC", "SDFC", "FSADC", "DSZXC", "SDAFC", "AFSDZC", "WFADS", "FSDVC", "GSDHBXC", "EFWADSCXZ", "EWAFDSC", "AFDSCZ", "AWEFDC", "AGSFV"), class = "factor"), baseline_pupilsize = c(6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6), baseline_coe = c(11.19, 13.6, 3.96, 7.64, 6.12, 6.92), baseline_rcb = c(16.74, 25, 25, 18.37, 25, 25), final_pop = c(NA, NA, 7.1, 8, 6, NA), final_coe = c(NA, NA, 5.9263624, 4.89, 11.98, NA), final_rcb = c(NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("participant_id", "baseline_pop", "baseline_coe", "baseline_rcb", "final_pop", "final_coe", "final_rcb"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

These are time-varying data from a longitudinal study, and a subset of a much larger dataset that I'm importing from source files. I'd like to extract the values `pop`, `coe` and `rcb` for both the `baseline` and `final` study visits (in my complete dataset there are several visits in between, which I've omitted for the purposes of this question).

I can do the following:

```
reshape(dframe,idvar='participant_id',v.names = c('pop','coe','rcb'),varying = 2:length(dframe),direction='long')
```

However, this ends up with the values that should be in `pop` being labelled as `coe`. The documentation for `reshape2` tells me I should explicitly reference the `varying` values to avoid 'guessing'. So, I try this instead:

```
reshape(dframe,idvar='participant_id',v.names = c('pop','coe','rcb'),varying = c('baseline_pop','baseline_coe','baseline_rcb','final_pop','final_coe','final_rcb'),direction='long')
```

This results in *exactly the same output*, despite naming the `varying` argument explicitly. What am I doing wrong? Presumably, `pop` ends up with `coe`'s values due to alphabetisation, but I can't understand why this has happened since I have now declared the `varying` argument explicitly...

**EDIT:** The expected output would be as follows:

```
participant_id  time    pop coe         rcb
FDVCZX          1       6   11.19       16.74
ADSCXZ          1       6   13.6        25
AESFDZC         1       7   3.96        25
ZXCV            1       6   7.64        18.37
AGS             1       6   6.12        25
AGSFV           1       6   6.92        25
FDVCZX          2       NA  NA          NA
ADSCXZ          2       NA  NA          NA
AESFDZC         2       7.1 5.926362    25
ZXCV            2       8   4.89        NA
AGS             2       6   11.98       NA
AGSFV           2       NA  NA          NA
```

However, as you will see, the `pop` values end up in the `coe` column, and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @akrun: Done as requested.

Comment: I posted a solution.  Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect. And, I had never heard of `data.table()`s until now, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`, which can take multiple `measure` columns.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dframe), measure=patterns('pop', 'coe', 'rcb'), 
     value.name = c('pop', 'coe', 'rcb'), variable.name='time')
#    participant_id time pop       coe   rcb
# 1:         FDVCZX    1 6.0 11.190000 16.74
# 2:         ADSCXZ    1 6.0 13.600000 25.00
# 3:        AESFDZC    1 7.0  3.960000 25.00
# 4:           ZXCV    1 6.0  7.640000 18.37
# 5:            AGS    1 6.0  6.120000 25.00
# 6:          AGSFV    1 6.0  6.920000 25.00
# 7:         FDVCZX    2  NA        NA    NA
# 8:         ADSCXZ    2  NA        NA    NA
# 9:        AESFDZC    2 7.1  5.926362 25.00
#10:           ZXCV    2 8.0  4.890000    NA
#11:            AGS    2 6.0 11.980000    NA
#12:          AGSFV    2  NA        NA    NA
```